# How do I create a nested table using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I have created the following in Oracle PSL/SQL:

I have created a type `Animal`.
This has the attributes: Name, Age

I have created the type `Dog`. This inherits from type `Animal`
The only extra field in `Dog`is a nested table of references of place lived.  I want to store all instances of `Dog`in the Animal table.

This is the bit I am confused about:  When creating the Animal table of type `Animal`, how do I create the nested table for `places lived`? There is no field in `Animal` for this, only in `Dog`.

Comment: this may be an example only - but not a good schema design.  the animal should not contain any reference to places lived - that is a normalization problem

Comment: @Randy - object-oriented programming is largely about hierarchies rather than relationships.  Hence normalization is irrelevant here.  It's the root cause of the "object-relational impedance".  But given that Oracle's OO implementation allows nested table it is legitimate to want to know how to use them.

Comment: @vikiiii - fnord.  I don't think you grasp how inheritance and polymorphism work in an object-oriented programming.

Comment: @APC - acknowledged - i was just pointing out that maybe this is not the best real world example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "When creating the Animal table of type Animal, how do I create the
>   nested table for "places lived"? when there is no field in Animal for
>   this, only in Dog."

This is the mystery of inheritance.  A table built from the type ANIMAL actually has columns to support the attributes of its sub-types.  However, they are only accessible when we explicitly use the DOG sub-type.

Here is your data structure.

```
create or replace type animal_t as object 
  ( name varchar2(10)
    , age number (3,0))
not final;
/

create or replace type places_nt as table of varchar2(20)
/

create or replace type dog_t under animal_t
 ( residence_history places_nt)
/

create table animals of animal_t;
```

To create a record for a goldfish we do this:

```
insert into animals
  values (animal_t('BOB', 7))
/
```

To create a record for a dog we need to do this:

```
insert into animals
  values (dog_t('FIDO', 12, places_nt('Balham', 'Tooting')))
/
```

This query will just select the generic columns:

```
SQL> select * from animals
  2  /

NAME              AGE
---------- ----------
BOB                 7
FIDO               12

SQL>
```

To gain sight of the details pertaining to dogs we need to cast the record to the relevant sub-type:

```
SQL> select treat(value(a) as dog_t)
  2  from animals a
  3  where value(a) is of (dog_t)
  4  /

TREAT(VALUE(A)ASDOG_T)(NAME, AGE, RESIDENCE_HISTORY)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOG_T('FIDO', 12, PLACES_NT('Balham', 'Tooting'))

SQL>
```

There is an entire book in the Oracle documentation devoted to its Object-Relational features.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#i479093).

---

Note: I have used an object table here simply because it is easy to illustrate how nested tables work.  I do not recommend using types for data storage: OO is a programming paradigm and should only be used for writing programs.  Data should always be persisted in relational structures.

Comment: thanks so much for this  
This has helped me tremendously!! :D
Just out of interest, what is your favourite editor for writing PSL/SQL?

Comment: @dewijones92 - for most of my career I have been happy with TextPad and SQL*Plus.  However, recently I have become enamoured of Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer: the license is quite reasonable and it works very well.